# sqlite tables don't need column names?

Tags: sqlite

In sqlite I was able to create a table with the following command:

```
create table myTable(varchar, date, int);
```

Notice that there are no column names! I discovered this when I used column names, and when I executed a where statement, it didn't work with the column name, but it worked when I specified the variable type instead. What's up with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But they became names instead of datatypes:

```
sqlite> create table myTable(varchar, date, int);
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> insert into myTable Values(1,1,1);
sqlite> select * from myTable;
varchar|date|int
1|1|1
```

Comment: How would you write it to give them names?

Comment: @javascript-ninja, `create table myTable(a1 varchar, a2 date, a3 int);`, but you should definitely visit the docs: http://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Comment: Oh, I see. I was doing it backwards. I was putting the type before the name.